# Choose not to support iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, frame-rate

I am building an app that is a bit heavy on graphics and it runs with a poor framerate on the iPhone 4 but runs fine on 4S and 5. Is there a way to choose not to support 4 and earlier?

I've seen apps that say it won't work in the description but is there a way to actually stop people from downloading it unless on a 4S and up?

EDIT:

My App was rejected for requiring Bluetooth-Le.

Answer (score 4):

No, currently there is no way of targeting specific devices in you app release.

**EDIT**

While what I stated above still holds true, there is a feasible workaround for targeting only iPhone 4S and iPhone 5.
In fact, you cannot target a device, but you can target a device capability and according to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/B_DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH17-SW1) document, there's a capability that only iPhone 4S and iPhone 5 have: the **`bluetooth-le`**.

Therefore if you target for that specific device capability, only those devices will be supported.

In order to do so, simply include the `bluetooth-le` capability under the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your application's plist.

## Disclaimer

As per the OP's experience, your app may be **rejected** for requiring a capability without using it.

Comment: Okay thanks, I've heard I can choose to support iPhone 5 and up due to architecture "support armv7s only.", but I still think there is a huge chunk of people using the 4S unfortunately.

Comment: actually I may have found a solution, just give me a few minutes to update my answer

Comment: Wow that would be amazing, I wonder if it'll be approved if I don't actually use it. I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I don't see any explicit policy about it and I hardly think that the actual usage is going to be checked in the approval phase.

Comment: Know a place where I could see what devices support bluetooth-le?
Just to know what iPads and iPods will support this, but thanks heaps for the solution.

Comment: there's a link in my answer ;)

Comment: I must be blind because I see no link haha.

Comment: Anyway you can easily target only iPhones, playing again with plist options. Requiring `telephony` will automatically exclude all iPod touche and iPad models.

Comment: @McDanGarrett it's over the word `this`, but I will repost it to you http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/B_DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH17-SW1

Comment: Ahhh wow completely missed it, thanks heaps.
Works perfectly, according to that it cuts off all the devices that couldn't handle it.

Comment: My App was rejected for requiring 'Bluetooth-le' and not using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your app target under Info > Custom iOS Target Proprieties.

You cand find more details about this on the apple documentation at [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html).

What you have to do is to require some capabilities that there are not supported by iPhone4.

**UPADTE**

Edited the screenshot based on the @Gabriele Petronella's answer

[image]

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm learning how to use the system and I don't want to offence nobody, if it's not ok I can delete the answer

Comment: Don't worry, just when you post an answer check whether it's adding something different that hasn't been said yet. In this case the screenshot may be helpful for someone, so leave your answer there ;)

Comment: My App was rejected for requiring 'Bluetooth-le' and not using it.